# How can i get access to the object of the window class from the page's class?

Tags: wpf

the problem is that i have a method, which is called by a click on a button on the page:

```
public void Go_to_saves(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

it should call a method, which is declared in the window class:

```
public void Navigate_to(string source) =>  main_frame.Navigate(new Uri("source"));
```

but i don't have the access to the window object in the page's class.
Pls help me to get somehow access to the object of my window class or suggest another way i can control navigation of pages from a certain page.
Sorry for this, I'm new to WPF

Comment: You can access it by using the static class Application: Application.Current.MainWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My instinct would be to use an event. The `Page` doesn't doesn't know about the `Window`, but the `Window` *does* know about the `Page`. You could declare an event in your `Page` and have the `Window` attach an event handler when it loads said `Page`. The `Page` would then raise the event when the `Button` is clicked, which would invoke the event handler in the `Window`.

Here's an MSDN article to get you started: [Handling and Raising Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)

Alternatively, you could pass a reference to the `Window` from the `Window` to the `Page` when the `Window` loads it. That would let you call `Window` methods directly, but that's not quite as "clean" in my opinion.